# Highchart Absolute Percentage Stacked Area

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have 10 series in one chart and using the Percentage Stacked Area chart type in Highchart, I can get the percentage distribution for each series.

However, when I deselect one series from the legend, it recalculate the percentage by only the active series. How do I tell Highchart to use the original total series instead of the active ones only?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `chart.ignoreHiddenSeries` to false, see: http://jsfiddle.net/quthyjta/

API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.ignoreHiddenSeries

Comment: It's almost what I needed. But I still want the UI to expand (without the value changes) instead of the second series floating on top. Is that possible?

Comment: @jlbriggs - could you undelete your answer? I think in the above conditions this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3d3fuhbb/100/ works flawlessly!